# Volumes of revolution.

Tags: calculus

How do I find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the area enclosed between $\sqrt{x},\ \sqrt{4-x}$ and the $x$-axis around the line $y = -1$ using the shell method.

I know it is an easy one but I'm not sure about my answer.

** I only need the integral and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get $$\int_0^\sqrt{2} 2\pi(1+y)(4-2y^2)dy.$$

The curves in terms of y are $x=y^2$ and $x=4-y^2$ and they intersect at $x=2$, $y = \sqrt{2}.$ Using the shell method $2\pi rhdy$, the "r" is $(1+y)$ and the "h" is $((4-y^2)-y^2)$ = $4-2y^2.$

Comment: Thank you , I got the same integral but it was different than the integral I got from solving by the washers method. Seems like I've done something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the disk method is messy in this case: $\int_0^2 \pi((\sqrt{x}+1)^2-1)dx + \int_2^4\pi((\sqrt{4-x}+1)^2-1)dx$

Comment: The problem is that when I evaluate each they give different results.

Comment: When I plug both shell and washer expressions into wolfram alpha, they give the same thing.